# AVAudioPlayer plays above When I Get into its View Controller more than ones

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I Have a question, I'm playing an `AVAudioPlayer` in a view `controller(appMusicViewController)`, I set my session as `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`, it runs good, when I navigate to other views the boundle music sounds in the background, but when I'm back in the `appMusicViewController` and I touch the play button, it doesn't stop the last play, so it plays the music at the same time. how can `appMusicViewController` knows the info of the last `AVAudioPlayer` allocated ?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{

[super viewDidLoad];

playList=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"David Keller - Klangkissen (Extended       Version)",@"Karmon - Wowshit (Original Mix) HQ",@"Phonique - Feel What You Want Feat.  Rebecca",@"Toky - About You (Original Mix)", nil]; // 4 SONGS
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error: nil];

artWork=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"David Keller - Klangkissen (Extended Version).jpg",@"Karmon - Wowshit (Original Mix) HQ.jpg",@"Phonique - Feel What You Want Feat. Rebecca.jpg",@"Toky - About You (Original Mix).jpg", nil];


NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[playList objectAtIndex:count] ofType: @"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];
myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];


myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
myAudioPlayer.delegate=self;

myAudioPlayer.volume=self.volume.maximumValue/2;
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{

[myAudioPlayer play];
playing=YES;


}
```